# Popup menu on top of view that starts it

Tags: android, layout, popupmenu

I have a problem with PopupMenu position in android.
Here's the thing: 
When I create a widget that matches the whole screen but ActionBar and then create the PopupMenu for that element, it gets created on the ActionBar and it's very thin (probably not to cover the widget). Is there a way to force android to show the PopupMenu on the middle of the screen?

Code is extremely basic

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ibAddPhoto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/start"
    android:onClick="showPopup"/>


public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions_photo, popup.getMenu());

    popup.show();
}
```

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: if you want it to be in the center of the screen you might be better off using a Dialog then a PopupWindow.